# AnchorPane round corners javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx-2, scenebuilder

How to make corners of AnchorPane **round** in SceneBuilder JavaFX?
I tried it using CSS

```
-fx-background-radius : 30;
-fx-border-radius : 30;
```

After this, it curves the graphic on top not the actual stage. It still has a sharp white edge visible. 
How to remove this.
Shouldn't this be **Transparent** to make it actually curve?

Comment: To elaborate and explain why this is a suspected duplicate; what you are likely noticing isn't that the `AnchorPane` itself has a sharp white edge, but rather the underlying components that contain it (the `Scene` and/or `Stage`) do.  Feel free to post updated information and an [mcve] if the marked duplicate does not help.

Comment: @Ironcache Thanks a lot, buddy. I came across that answer earlier but I couldn't understand it. Now that you explained it, its fine now. Thanks.